# How to install WorkerService in C# and .Net 5

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services, setup-project, .net-5

Previously (before .net 5) we could add a custom `Installer` which inherit `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` to our project, and then the Setup packet used it to install Service to windows.

Now, there is no `System.Configuration.Install` DLL until now.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0

I knew there are some NuGet packages, but I'm looking for an official solution.

How can I change the `WorkerService` (**Service**) `ServiceName`, `DisplayName` and `Description`?

How can I create a setup packet for my `WorkerService` (**Service**)?

Comment: are you looking for something command line oriented, or more in line with the functionality provided by System.Configuration.Install ?

Comment: @elliot-j I'm looking for something like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: because Microsoft is pursing a cross-plaform philosophy for .NET 5, your best bet would be nuget packages at this point. System.Configuration.Install was tailored to specific features in Windows which other platforms would undoubtable lack. Which is why something like it does not currently exist in .NET 5

Comment: @ImranShamszadeh did you figure out a solution to your question?

Comment: @Aiyuni not jet

Comment: @ImranShamszadeh yes, the System.Configuration.Install.Installer assembly is not available in .NET Core. I already answered a similar question in detail like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68998620/2671158