# Where is ServiceProcessInstaller on Net5?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, .net-5

In the past I used the classes [Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer?view=netframework-4.8), [ServiceInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) and [ServiceProcessInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) to make my app self-installable.
I just had to run `InstallUtil.exe MyApp` to install the app as a Windows Service.

But I can't find those classes on DotNet5.

They won't be ported?
There are any other approach to replace them?
Can anyone point me to some documentation on how to achieve this goal?

Here goes an example on how those classes were used in the past:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
  private string serviceName = "MyApp";

  public MyServiceInstaller()
  {
    var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
    var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

    processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    processInstaller.Username = null;
    processInstaller.Password = null;

    serviceInstaller.ServiceName = serviceName;
    serviceInstaller.DisplayName = serviceName;
    serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

    this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
    this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);

    this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(MyServiceInstaller_Committed);
  }

  void MyServiceInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
  {
    var controller = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    controller.Start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... That's interesting.  I can find online discussions about why that class (and a few others) were skipped, but the discussions date way back to the early days of Core.  Every example I can find installs core services using `sc create`, not using `installutil`

Answer (score 3):

We can find these classes/libraries available in Assembly Core .System.ServiceProcess nuget package which is compatible from .Net 5, 6 and latest versions. Install this Nuget Package in visual studio on the project required.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Windows Service on top of .NET Core is different from creating Windows Service based on .NET Framework, because all of the required infrastructure for Windows Service such as Installer (not to be confused with MSI installer) is no longer available by default in .NET Core SDK.

This is for good reason, as by default .NET Core SDK is cross platform. Therefore for OS/platform specific, the supports are usually available outside the .NET Core SDK as nuget packages.

To create Windows Service in .NET Core, the service must run within a runtime host that act as Windows Service.
To support this, you need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` in your code base. This nuget will provide you the host environment for Windows Service.

The detail steps are available in this official blog from Windows dev team:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/creating-a-windows-service-with-c-net5/

NOTE: that blog is applicable for both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0.

Comment: Yeah, you right on that. I understand what you said and a I did it. What I can't get done though is to turn my component self-installable as I used to do in the past. All because I can't figure out a way to replace the installer classes Installer, ServiceInstaller and ServiceProcessInstaller. It was so easy to install a service in the days of dotnet framework. Maybe we have to do it all by hand now, like messing around with sc.exe, but I still hope to find an automated solution.

Comment: There's no automated solution. Even in .NET Framework, you still have to run InstallUtil to install your .NET Framework based Windows Service. What exactly do you mean automated solution compared to .NET Core?

Comment: I mean, to have the rules to install the component inside the component itself. InstallUtil, MSI packages and other installers can read the Installer classes when they are present in the assembly, like in the sample code I provided above. In the past I just had to inherit the class `Installer` and code my rules in the events BeforeInstall, AfterInstall, Commit, etc, making the component therefore self-installable.

Comment: @GugaCoder Understood. Ok, feel free to update your question whether my answer will answer your question or not. If my answer answered your question, please mark it as answer. Currently, as far as I know, there's no same way in .NET Core to have Windows Service like .NET Framework way.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced same issue during migration from NET Framework 4.8 into .NET6.

My classes like **ServiceProcessInstaller/ServiceInstaller/ServiceAccount** could not be found.

After further investigating I found and add this NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Core.System.ServiceProcess and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, only want to show, where exactly was issue. I will not do it in a future :-)

Comment: The problem isn't showing, the problem is the way you showed, (in case you didn't read the post linked in my initial comment) instead of using images, use (formatted) text (and while keeping this in mind is good for your next posts, you can already [edit] this post to fix here)

Comment: Fixed. Please reset your vote, it could help somebody and negative rating could discourage somebody